# no datanodes created when running "jps" command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, datanode

I'm new at Hadoop and when I run "jps" command shows that no data node exist but when I run stop-all.sh or start-all.sh it shows that there is a data node started and stopped how can I solve this issue
I tried so many solutions but no one works also I modified hdfs-site.xml but the problem is still exist

here is a "jps" command
[image: here is a "jps" command]

here is    /hadoop-moazuser-datanode-moaz-VirtualBox.out.1

```
ore file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 32992
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 32992
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

and vim ./hadoop.log.2021-10-19

```
2021-10-19 03:21:17,065 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2021-10-19 03:21:25,141 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2021-10-19 03:21:29,694 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2021-10-19 03:21:30,479 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2021-10-19 03:21:31,305 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2021-10-19 03:21:39,631 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of the datanode log?  It might help to figure out what's happening.

Comment: hi matt andruff, iam new at hadoop can you tell me how to get the log file, thank you?

Comment: It depends, Almost all hadoop logs should be located in $HADOOP_HOME/logs which is usually: /var/log/[name of component]
Here I think they'll be located under /var/log/hdfs/ if memory serves me correctly.

Comment: 2021-10-19 03:21:17,065 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2021-10-19 03:21:25,141 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2021-10-19 03:21:29,694 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform...

Comment: 2021-10-19 03:21:30,479 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2021-10-19 03:21:31,305 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2021-10-19 03:21:39,631 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform

Comment: i delete "... using builtin-java classes where applicable" from the last two lines for comments because of chars limits

Comment: ore file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 32992
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited

Comment: max user processes              (-u) 32992
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

Comment: Maybe you could add the message to the originial post in a code block for readablility?

Comment: You need to show the datanode process logs, not the `.out` file